# Replacing GELU with ReLU in BERT inference

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model

I have a question for what concerns BERT.
Actually it uses GELU activation function since it performs better than ReLU, but this is because of the gradient near zero. In inference, we do not really care about gradients (are we?), so would it be a stupid idea to replace GELU with ReLU at inference (even at the cost of slightly losing accuracy) for achieving higher throughput?

I expect it to be really similar to GELU, since the difference is really tiny (not for what concerns gradient, but that's another story)

Answer (score 0):

In this submission to ICLR 2023, the authors are replacing GELU with ReLU

MA-BERT: Towards Matrix Arithmetic-only BERT Inference by
Eliminating Complex Non-Linear Functions
https://openreview.net/forum?id=HtAfbHa7LAL

so yes in some cases, ReLU seems ok, simpler in